# Regex to match dollar sign, money, decimals only

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

*Regex*

```
y = [X: $1.19] [Y: $5.29] [Z 999/1000]
x = re.findall(r"\$[^ ]+", y)
```

*Matches*

```
$1.19] 
$5.29]
```

*Expected Matches*

```
$1.19
$5.29
```

---

***How can I adjust my regex to match a money amount which could include decimals and must include the dollar sign? - these values can change. E.G:***

```
$x.xx # 'x' representing a number
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace the space within your negated-character class with closed bracket:

```
In [37]: x = re.findall(r"\$[^\]]+", y)

In [38]: x
Out[38]: ['$1.19', '$5.29']
```

Comment: Please escape the `]`, it's freaking me out. And if a future version of python ever supports empty negated character sets, your pattern will break.

Comment: @Rawing :-) OK, here you go!

Comment: Great, Thanks very much!

Comment: @Kasrâmvd would `re.match()` work with a `$`. for instance `if re.match(r"\$","ff $ ff") : print ('yes')` won't print. Both  by using `r"\$"` and `"\$"`

Answer (score 24):

You can simply search with following regex.

**Regex:** `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

**Explanation:**

`\$`: ensures dollar sign followed by

`\d+`: one or more digits

`(?:\.\d+)?`: decimal part which is optional

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQjcHp/2/)

Comment: Slight error in the explanation: It doesn't match "more than one digits", it matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

**Best Regular Expressions for this case is**

```
\$\d+(?:.(\d+))?
```

**Explanation**

***\$*** shows it should starts with a dollar sign

***\d+*** matches all numbers before decimal

***(?:.(\d+))*** matches if there are any numbers after the decimal. For example in **$1.12** it would match **.12** and capture 12 (part after the decimal) . If the money is **$1.** it would only match **$1** it would not match **.**

**[Regular Expression tester, library, tutorials and cheat sheet.](http://allregex.com)**

Answer (score 1):

`[\$ ]+?(\d+([,\.\d]+)?)`

**Explanation**

`[\$ ]+?` accept dollar, replace `\$` with the currency of your need

`(\d+([,\.\d]+)?)` digits with comma and period repeated any number of times. Doesn't matter UK numbering system or R